# is there a url for opening roundcube calendar the day of a given event?

Tags: roundcube, kolab

I wrote a web apps that create a kolab Event et put it in calendar.

now, i wish to create link in my apps that will go to the identified event directly in  roundcube.

since in Know the day, it could be possible to give a date instead of the ID of the event.

anyone know of such feature in Roundcube ?

Answer (score 0):

with some luck, I found my Answer by navigating in the calendar. if a go to the «next week», the url change in we got a beautiful

```
https://kolab.mydomaine.fr/roundcubemail/?_task=calendar&view=agendaWeek&date=1392678000
```

with date = the timestamp of the day I wish to show.

so, with a little python (using django)

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    timestamp = int(time.mktime(self.event.get_start().timetuple()))
    return "https://{kolab_domaine}/roundcubemail/?_task=calendar&view=agendaWeekdate={timestamp}".format(kolab_domaine=self.get_kolab_domain(), timestamp=timestamp)
```